# Ways to clean up photos for Tesseract OCR?

Tags: python, image, ocr, tesseract

I'm new to Tesseract and wanted to know if there were any ways to clean up photos for a simple OCR program to get better results. Thanks in advance for any help!
The code I am using:

```
#loads tesseract
tess.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 
#filepath
file_path = 
image = Image.open(file_path)
#processes image
text = tess.image_to_string(image, config='')
print(text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used `pytesseract` in the past and with the following four modifications, I could read almost anything as long as the text font wasn't too small to begin with. `pytesseract` seems to struggle with small writing, even after resizing.

*- Convert to Black & White -*

Converting the images to black and white would frequently improve the recognition of the program. I used [OpenCV](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) to do so and got the code from the end of this [article](https://techtutorialsx.com/2019/04/13/python-opencv-converting-image-to-black-and-white/).

*- Crop -*

If all your photos are in similar format, as in the text you need is always in the same spot, I'd recommend [cropping](https://www.includehelp.com/python/cropping-an-image-using-opencv.aspx) your pictures. If possible, pass only the exact part of the photo to `pytesseract` that you want analyzed, the less the program has to analyze, the better. In my case, I was taking screenshots and would specify the exact region of where to take one.

*- Resize -*

Another thing you can do is to play with the scaling of the original photo. Sometimes after [resizing](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/image-resizing-using-opencv-python/) to almost double it's initial size `pytesseract` could read the text a lot easier. Generaly,  bigger text is better but there's a limit as the photo can become too pixelated after resizing to be recognizable.

*- Config -*

I've noticed that `pytesseract` can recognize text a lot easier than numbers. If possible, break the photo down into sections and whenever you have a trouble spot with numbers you can use:

`pytesseract.image_to_string(image, config='digits')`